# Which web browsers support the HTML5 attribute sortable?

Tags: html

I did not find the answer on the Consortium's official website (https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-table-element - https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-html51-20140617/tabular-data.html#attr-table-sortable) and neither on the Mozilla developer web site (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes).

Thanks for your time.

```html
<table sortable>
  <tr>
   <th sorted> 1 </th>
   <th sorted> 2 </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td> aaa </td>
   <td> bbb </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td> xxx </td>
   <td> zzz </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I highly doubt sortable is an attribute recognised by the browser to do sorting—it is likely added by a plugin, or required by a plugin in a markup. Where did you learn about this attribute from?

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-html51-20140617/tabular-data.html#attr-table-sortable

Comment: `sortable` only seems to be mentioned in an old working draft. It's not mentioned in the latest draft. Consider that it simply didn't make the cut somewhere.

Comment: This could be a feature for http://caniuse.com

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sortable` <strike>is a</strike>  was an attribute in HTML 5.1 that was supposed to be included earlier but now it is deprecated. So no browsers currently supports it. For more information, refer [this](https://w3c.github.io/test-results/html51/implementation-report.html)

Answer (score 3):

The table sorting model that had been in the HTML spec [was removed in January 2016](https://github.com/whatwg/html/commit/59b7e2466c2b7c5c408a4963b05b13fd808aa07a).

So [it’s not correct that `sortable` is an attribute that’s part of an “upcoming HTML version and is not officially released](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/41359718/revisions)”. The W3C HTML 5.1 spec is [a final Recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/) that has since been superseded and anyway [the `sortable` attribute was not in HTML 5.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/tabular-data.html#the-table-element).

No browsers ever natively supported the `sortable` attribute and none ever will unless/until it ends up being re-specified again later. The reason it’s not included in http://caniuse.com/—and never was included in it—is that caniuse.com doesn’t track features that have zero browser support.